# Scripting customization for ArcPad AXF file?

Tags: arcpad

I have an [ArcPad](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcpad) AXF file, created from a geodatabase.  I've opened the AXF in ArcPad Studio and created some a custom edit form.  It's all great.

But if the original geodatabase ever gets destroyed and I have to create a new AXF file, I will lose my custom forms, right?

Is there a way to script all that XML that makes up the custom form?

I really don't want to have go through all that ArcPad Studio GUI editing again.

I can see that it is possible to save the XML of a layer (including the custom edit form XML) as a .apl in ArcPad studio.

But how can I push that saved XML back into a new XML file?

Is there a way to script this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I now see that you can use an AXF template file during the initial checkout from ArcPad Data Manager.  Still, it would be cool if you could just script it.

Comment: That is the only solution I have ever come across. Arcpad can be really useful but it does feel very dated compared to the rest of the ESRI products, and indeed other vendors offerings.

Comment: Agreed sgrieve, any attempts at technical support from ESRI on ArcPad and they just push ArcGIS Mobile on you.  It's crazy that they continue to sell a product that they have no intention of supporting.

Comment: the main advantage of Arcpad , i think that is designed for offline surveys, while arcgis mobile is for online

Comment: yup, and ArcGIS Mobile for Windows is not fun either.  They're not even supporting Visual Studio 2010 yet.

Comment: @Roy Yeah, I've noticed that too. Which sucks, as ArcPad does so much more out of the box!

Answer (score 0):

you can be independent towards AXF file by scripting in applets level. so won't care about the  manner you made check ins , the script will always work